# Spring security - remember me can not save cookie when closed browser

Tags: java, spring

I am having problems with Spring security.
When i using default security everything is working
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dwJQ.png
,but when i using it, cookie not working
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLM37.png
Cookies are still created when I log in, but when I closed my browser, the cookie disappears.
When i login:
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FghHk.png
When i closed browser:
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/av0ca.png
Please help me, thanks!